# Shell scripting to form dynamic arrays and trigger a process based on it

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, arguments, dynamic-arrays

Hi I have a requirement.

I should run a script with number of arguments specified as below case.
E.g ./build.sh a b checkout c build d e deploy

a,b,c,d,e,f are name of the instances and checkout, build, deploy are the name of the processes.

So i can run any of instances with any of the processes.

Now tel me how can i seperate the aruguments and use them in a shell script.

If the arguments are of similar type, i can use them in an array and check each of them using a for loop and switch case.

Here in my case, I have to separate the arguments and make it run like

1. checkout for a and b.
2. build for c
3. deploy for d and e

Need to form number of dynamic arrays and operations like

1. a, b should form an array and that should detect checkout and start
   executing.
2. similar to that c should form an array and that should detect build
   process and start executing.
3. d and e should form an array and run deploy process.

Suggest me if there are any other way of implementing it and provide me with solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old-school POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Note: Inside the functions, $@, $1 etc. refer to the arguments to the function,
# whereas outside they refer to the arguments to the whole script.    
foo() {
    echo foo $@
}

bar() {
    echo bar $3 $2 $1 
}

PARAMS=

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do    # while there are arguments
    case "$1" in          # check if the front argument is a command
    foo)                  # if so, run it with the previously cached parameters
        foo $PARAMS       # (see below)
        PARAMS=
        ;;
    bar)
        bar $PARAMS
        PARAMS=
        ;;
    *)                    # if it is not a command, cache the parameter in the
        PARAMS+=" $1"     # $PARAMS variable
        ;;
    esac

    shift                 # shift the arguments back; what was $2 is now $1
done
```

Called as `./foo.sh 1 2 foo 3 4 5 bar`, this gives

```
foo 1 2
bar 5 4 3
```

If you need to use bash arrays instead, the syntax for that is

```
PARAMS=()       # instead of PARAMS=
PARAMS+=("$1")  # instead of PARAMS+=" $1"
${PARAMS[0]}    # instead of $1, analogous for $2, $3 etc.
```

The rest remains the same, and of course you can call other things than functions with the parameter array.

Comment: But i need to get the output as below. 
1 2 in an arary ==> which should initiate foo.....
3 4 5 in an array ==> which should initiate bar .....
Please help me

Comment: But...I already wrote how you could do that. With which part are you having problems?